# Migrate old Visual Studio projects to VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I'm planning to migrate all existing projects running/using VS 2010/2012/2013/2015 (Framework 4.0/4.5/4.5.2) to VS 2017.

Please advise on following if you've any idea or done this before:

1. Is there any issue in doing this?
2. Does it require major changes to projects?
3. Do I need to consider any other thing with regards to compatibility?

Regards,

Jony

Comment: I think it's a bit depending on which version you use, I think some projects can be opened with VS 2017 right away without the need to migrate them (maybe only move them from the old map to a newer one) Though I'm not very certain about the 2010 / 2012 versions.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, somehow my fortran programs started to behave strangely, even thought they compiled,

2) No, but since my answer one, it might need on some projects,

3) You will need the new frameworks, also, visual studio 2017 is much slower than visual studio 2010